# An inequality about second fundamental form under volume preserving mean curvature flow.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

If $M_t$ evolve under volume preserving mean curvature flow, assume
$$
A=(h_{ij})
$$
is the second fundamental form of $M_t$, and
$$
|A|^2=h_i^jh_j^i
$$
then, we have
$$
\partial_t|A|^2= \Delta |A|^2- 2|\nabla A|^2+ 2|A|^4 - 2h ~tr(A^3)   \tag{1}
$$
where $tr(A^3) = h_i^j h_j^k h_k^i$, and
$$
h(t)=\frac{\int_{M_t} HdS }{\int_{M_t} dS}
$$
Now, how to get
$$
\partial _t |A|\le \Delta |A| + |A|^3 + h|A|^2
$$
from (1) ?

PS: this question origins from the 337th page of

*Li, Haozhao*, [**The volume-preserving mean curvature flow in Euclidean space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2009.243.331), Pac. J. Math. 243, No. 2, 331-355 (2009). [ZBL1182.53061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1182.53061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\partial _t |A|^2 = 2|A|\; \partial _t |A|$$ and

$$\Delta |A|^2 = 2|A| \Delta |A| + 2|\nabla |A||^2.$$

Using Kato's inequality we have $|\nabla |A|| \le |\nabla A|$ and

$$ |\operatorname{tr} (A^3)| \le |A|^3$$

by applying Cauchy-Schwarz twice, we obtain

$$2|A| \partial _t |A| \le 2|A| \Delta |A| + 2|A|^4 + 2h |A|^3, $$
which implies the inequality.

Comment: What is $|A|$ ？ I dont understand it, since only $|A|^2$ is defined, it is the determine of $A$ ?

Comment: $|A|$ is just the square roof of $|A|^2$. @lanse7pty